# Alternative of setSource in springDefinitionBuilder in Spring 4.0.X-beans

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">
    <security:http access-denied-page="/jsp/403.jsp">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login/reDirect.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login/reDirect.jsp?error=true"
            default-target-url="/jsp/main.jsp" />
        <security:anonymous />
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout.action"
            logout-success-url="/login/login.jsp" />
    </security:http>
```

I got this error, while upgrating spring **2.5.6** to **4.0.4**:

```
    Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class                   
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration     problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:com/essar/mes/hpl/config/spring-security.xml]
    Offending resource: class path resource [com/essar/mes/hpl/config/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [com/essar/mes/hpl/config/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setSource(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
```

This indicates thats there is no method in setSource in springDefinationBuilder in Spring 4.0.X-beans

Is there any alternative to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You need at least Spring Security 3.0.0 for Spring 4, or you need an older Spring 3.2.x version for Spring Security 2.0.x. That method has been marked as deprecated starting with Spring 2.5 and removed completely in Spring 4.

Comment: Thank you for responding.Is there any way to use spring 4.0.4 and spring-security 2.5.6 together..???

Comment: I think you meant spring-security 2.0.x (there is no spring-security 2.5.6) or Spring 2.5.6. The answer to both my assumptions is "no". Spring 2.5.6 and Spring 4.0.4 or, better said, a mix of Spring versions is strongly not recommended. You'll get exceptions like ClassNotFoundExceptions or NoSuchMethodErrors or similar. Spring Security 2.0.x and Spring 4 will not work because of code incompatibilities mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Who calls the setSource method?